# VS Javascript Intellisense type being overwritten

Tags: javascript, dom, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am writing a JavaScript class and trying to declare a field as a specific HTML element with Visual Studio 2013 intellisense. The problem is when I set the field to the return of a value it overwrites the intellisense to the return types value (even though I know it's the XML type I set it to).

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the automatic overwrite of the field type.

Here is a contrived example:

```
myClass = function myClass()
{
    /// <summary>Dummy class to demonstrate intellisense type overriding</summary>
    /// <field name="fieldDiv" type="HTMLDivElement">The thing under question</field>
    fieldDiv = null;
};

myClass.prototype.myFunction = function myFunction()
{
    this.fieldDiv;    //Intellisense works correctly as if it was a div element
    this.fieldDiv = getEl("myDiv"); //This breaks the intellisense
    this.fieldDiv;    //Intellisense now thinks it's a generic dom object
                      //I want it to think it's still a div element
};
```

I wouldn't mind having to add an xml markup line right after the `this.field = getEl("myDiv");`. I just really want that div context information.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even realise you could use xml comments to do this, great!  Perhaps you need to add something to `getEl`?  It sounds like it already knows that it's returning an element as the intellisense suggests.  Maybe you need a wrapper `getDiv` that internally calls `getEl` but could be documented in an intellisense-friendly fashion?  Leaving as a comment and not an answer since a) I've never seen this functionality before, and b) there might be a proper way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, it works in my VS2013. On the third line shows *HTMLDivElement* type.
You can try adding inside your *getEl* function the return type signature. according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh542721(v=vs.120).aspx) (and Remarks section specifically). Example:

```
  function trim() {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.</summary>
    ///   <param name="str" type="String">The string to trim.</param>
    ///   <returns type="String" />
    /// </signature>
  }
```

Comment: The other weird thing is it still says it's HTMLDivElement, but it doesn't have any of the associated HTMLDivElement members/functions (ie, when you type `this.fieldDiv.` it should show all the DivElement stuff, but it doesn't). 
There is currently the function getEl, but it specifies a return type of Sys.UI.DomElement. I guess I was hoping to override that (kind of like a intellisense typecast, but I don't know how). The problem is I'm getting multiple types of HTML elements, so I can't just change the function for them all to work.